# How to estimate minimal efforts required to update trajectory of a moving ball?

Tags: kinematics

Let's imagine we've got a uniformly sampled curved trajectory of a moving ball in 3D space without gravity. Let's assume that some dynamic force is applied to the moving ball to update its trajectory between samples. Is it possible to estimate minimal efforts required to update trajectory of the moving ball between samples?

For example:
[image: Two examples of moving balls]

In case A there was no force applied between `t` and `t+1` because the ball moved with constant speed.

In case B some dynamic force changed position of the ball from `P(t)` to `P(t+1)`

I would like to know the way to estimate minimal efforts required to move the ball from `P(t)` to `P(t+1)` in general case.

## Edit:

One possible interpretation of "effort" might be the time integral of the magnitude of the force applied. This would quantify the total "scalar impulse" applied on the ball. This is also the relevant quantity when you want to perform a maneuver in a spacecraft by consuming the least amount of fuel (assuming the change in the mass of the spacecraft is negligible)

Comment: Are you given that no force is applied before $t$ and after $t+1$ in case B? Also, the minimal work required would be zero if the separation between P(t-1) and P(t), and between P(t+1) and P(t+2) remain the same as in case A. This would mean the speeds (and hence the kinetic energies) at P(t) and P(t+1) are the same, meaning no net work would be required.

Comment: @Puk the force might be applied at any time between samples

Comment: @Puk Kinetic energy of the ball at `t-1` and `t+1` might be the same, but some force had been applied to move from `P(t)` to `P(t+1)` to accelerate and decelerate the ball. That required non-zero work.

Comment: The force may do no work at all if it is always perpendicular to the velocity of the ball. If it isn't always perpendicular, it does some positive work and some negative work, for a total of zero work.

Comment: @Puk Thank you for your insight, I'll rephrase the question to estimate minimal energy to move from `P(t)` to `P(t+1)`

Comment: That would still be zero, because of the work-energy theorem. The net change of energy of the ball is zero between $t$ and $t+1$.

Comment: @Puk In case B I applied force to accelerate the ball "down" and then I applied force "up" to decelerate the ball so that at `t+1` it had the same impulse as it had at `t`. Although the ball at `P(t+1)` had the same kinetic energy as it had at `P(t)`, I "spent" energy which I could not restore.

Comment: In principle, you could "store" the energy you extract from the ball in a useful form. But even if you don't want to store this energy, as I indicated before, the force could guide the ball so that it only ever changes direction at constant speed following circular arcs. In this case the applied forces are centripetal (always orthogonal to the velocity), do no work and "spend" no energy.

Comment: @Puk Wow, I didn't think about changing position in arcs in order to not make any work at all! Ok, could you please help me to find a sensible measure that penalizes applying any force between samples?

Comment: @Puk Also, I should add another limitation that trajectory positions band limited by Nyquist rate.

Comment: I think a natural quantity to minimize would be the $\int F(t) dt$, i.e. the time integral of the magnitude of the force applied. This would quantify the total "scalar impulse" applied on the ball. This is also the relevant quantity when you want to perform a maneuver in a spacecraft by consuming the least amount of fuel (assuming the change in the mass of the spacecraft is negligible). I don't know what you mean by the positions being band limited. It seems to me that requiring the ball to pass through the points $P(t)$ and $P(t+1)$ at times $t$ and $t+1$ already enforces this condition.

Comment: @Puk Thank you, I replaced "energy" with "effort" and cited your words within the question. Also, please let me know if I should somehow emphasize that those words were yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can numerically estimate the acceleration of the path, by interpolating the data using a cubic spline or some other method in order to estimate the time derivatives of the positions. Then do it again to estimate the acceleration needed to follow the path. Finally, if you know the mass of the object, you can $\vec{F} = m \vec{a}$ to estimate force needed.

Below is an example using a single coordinate `X` as input (blue), and evaluating the speed `Xp` (red) and acceleration `Xpp` (green) in Excel.

[image: screen]

> I am using my own custom array function `Derivative(x_range,y_range)` to do the job.

Depending on what programming environment you have access to, try to find interpolating functions. They exist for `MATLAB`, `C`, `Fortran`, `Python`, `Java`, `C#` and all other major programming languages. You can try porting the `C` code from [NRBOOK](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) in section 3.3 relating to *Cubic Splines.*

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer, I came to the same conclusion at the end of the day, but I decided to interpolate using Lanczos kernel instead of cubic splines.