# Calculate acceleration and lateral G force from GPS coordinates

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, data, gps

I have a data logger that records time (in tenths of seconds), latitude and longitude. I would like to calculate my acceleration and lateral G force based on the collected data. Is someone able to help me with the formula? Here is sample data I am working with:

```
Time (seconds),Latitude,Longitude
0.1,53.330964,-113.592616
0.2,53.330962,-113.592628
0.3,53.330961,-113.592643
0.4,53.330961,-113.592656
0.5,53.330961,-113.59267
0.6,53.33096,-113.592698
0.7,53.33096,-113.592726
0.8,53.330959,-113.592755
0.9,53.330958,-113.592786
1,53.330958,-113.592816
1.1,53.330957,-113.592846
1.2,53.330956,-113.592878
1.3,53.330956,-113.59291
1.4,53.330956,-113.592942
1.5,53.330956,-113.592974
1.6,53.330956,-113.59301
1.7,53.330956,-113.593045
1.8,53.330956,-113.59308
1.9,53.330956,-113.593117
2,53.330956,-113.593155
2.1,53.330956,-113.593192
2.2,53.330956,-113.593229
2.3,53.330956,-113.593267
2.4,53.330956,-113.593306
2.5,53.330956,-113.593344
2.6,53.330956,-113.593384
2.7,53.330956,-113.593424
2.8,53.330956,-113.593464
2.9,53.330957,-113.593504
3,53.330958,-113.593544
3.1,53.330958,-113.593584
3.2,53.330959,-113.593624
3.3,53.33096,-113.593666
3.4,53.33096,-113.593707
3.5,53.33096,-113.593749
3.6,53.33096,-113.59379
3.7,53.33096,-113.593832
3.8,53.33096,-113.593872
3.9,53.33096,-113.593912
4,53.330961,-113.593952
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to estimate minimal efforts required to update trajectory of a moving ball?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/494308/how-to-estimate-minimal-efforts-required-to-update-trajectory-of-a-moving-ball)

Answer (score 2):

Given a latitude ($\phi$), longitude ($\lambda$), and height above ellipsoid ($h$), you can convert to Earth Center Earth Fixed coordinates via:

$$ x = \cos{\phi}\cos{\lambda}(N(\phi)+h)$$
$$ y = \cos{\phi}\sin{\lambda}(N(\phi)+h)$$
$$ z = \sin{\phi}([1-\epsilon^2]N(\phi)+h)$$

where $\epsilon$ is the eccentricity of the ellipsoid and the normal radius of curvature is:

$$ N(\phi) = \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{(a\cos{\phi})^2+(b\sin{\phi})^2}}$$

where $a$ ($b$) is the semi-major (semi-minor) axis of the ellipsoid.

GPS uses the WGS84 datum.

Answer (score 2):

Your data are obviously from a quite small area (compared to the size of the earth).
That means that the curvature of this area due to the shape
of the earth is certainly neglectable.
So you can approximate this area as a flat plane.

A further simplification is to treat the earth as a sphere
(with radius 6371 km) instead of as the real ellipsoid
(with equatorial radius 6378 km, and polar radius 6356 km).
This will introduce an error of less than 0.2%.

Then you can transform your GPS coordinates (latitude $\phi$,
longitude $\lambda$)
to horizontal cartesian coordinates ($x$ to east, $y$ to north)
relative to a reference point ($\phi_{\text{ref}}, \lambda_{\text{ref}}$) nearby.

The transformation is

$$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{2\pi R}{360°} (\lambda - \lambda_{\text{ref}}) \cos(\phi_{\text{ref}}) \\
y &= \frac{2\pi R}{360°} (\phi - \phi_{\text{ref}})
\end{align}$$

With a reference point at $\phi_{\text{ref}} = 53.33°$,
$\lambda_{\text{ref}} = -113.59°$
and radius of the earth $R = 6371 \text{ km}$, you get

```
Time(seconds),y(km),x(km)
0.1,0.1072,-0.1737
0.2,0.1070,-0.1745
0.3,0.1069,-0.1755
0.4,0.1069,-0.1764
...
```

Then you can numerically calculate the acceleration as the second derivative of $x$ and $y$ with respect to time.
For details read about [Finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference).

---

Since you are a newbie to kinematics I recommend some
entry-level videos to enable you grasping the basic concepts
and working out the calculations by yourself.

1. From your position data $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ you need
   to calculate the velocities $v_x(t)$ and $v_y(t)$.
   Look up the definition of [velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity) and watch the
   video [Kinematics - central difference method 1: velocity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eU-7dKCE--o).
   Apply these ideas to compute the velocities from your data.
2. From your calculated velocities $v_x(t)$ and $v_y(t)$
   you need to calculate the accelerations $a_x(t)$ and $a_y(t)$.
   Look up the definiton of [acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration) and watch the
   video [Kinematics - central difference method 2: acceleration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fUiDHtihl0).
   Apply these ideas to compute the accelerations from your data.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the help so far. I have correctly calculated y based on your formula however my x calculation is not matching yours. For the first row of sample data, I return 0.290022341 (111.1949266 * -0.002616 * -0.997031184
). Can you restate the x formula using the values 53.330964,-113.592616 as the variables. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Also, an example to calculate the acceleration and lateral g based on the x and y variables would be appreciated too.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: @bneuf You got the $\cos$ wrong. $\cos(53.33°)=0.5972$, but not $-0.9970$.
May be you calculated in radiants instead of in degrees. For how to calculate acceleration see the link I added at the end of my answer.

Comment: thanks for the additional help. I have now correctly calculated my x and y. I reviewed the linked you provided on finite differences but I'm afraid I need some additional hand-holding. Can you provide an example, using my sample data above where you calculated x and y, and illustrate the formula used to calculate acceleration and lateral G force?

Comment: @bneuf Are you already familiar with how velocity and acceleration are defined by differential quotients?

Comment: no, I am not familiar with differential quotients. The wiki is beyond my comprehension. If the wiki is what I need to understand to answer my question then I may be out of my element. Any dumbed-down direction is appreciated.

Comment: @bneuf See my added recommendations at the end of my answer.

Comment: thanks for all your direction. It is helpful. I reviewed the videos and did the calculations. The numbers look close but they don't seem exactly right. Can I trouble you to check the numbers below?
`Time (seconds),Elapsed Time,Latitude,Longitude, y (m) , x (m) , Velocity y (ms) , Velocity x (ms) , Acceleration y (ms) , Acceleration x (ms) ,Lateral G,Acceleration G, Distance (m) , Speed (kmh) 
0.4,0:00:00,53.330961,-113.592656,106.86,-176.37, -   ,-8.96,0,23.24,0,2.37,0.86328053,31.08`